# PictureBox.CreateGraphics not saving

Tags: c#, graphics, picturebox, pixel

I have a PictureBox called map and I draw graphics onto it

```
map.CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x+xx, y+yy, 1, 1);
```

It works absolutely fine, it draws the pixels, but when I attempt to save

```
map.Image.Save(@"C:\Users\Skye\Pictures\!Access\Map\map" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHmmss") + ".png");
```

Edit: I have tried various saving methods ImageFormat.Bmp/ImageFormat.Png/etc

It brings up an error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Terrain Genorator.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

In Autos it says

```
map.Image       null
```

1. How can I save pixels?

or

2. How can I save pixels drawn on a PictureBox?

Comment: When you use *CreateGraphics()* you dont actually draw **in** the control but **where** the control is. The control doesnt "know" anything about the drawing. So, create a bitmap, load an image in it, set the bitmap as map.Image, draw on the bitmap, invalidate and save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution with thanks to @valter

Make in Bitmap, make picturebox show the image, save either bitmap or picturebox.

```
Bitmap mapImage;
mapImage = new Bitmap(pWidth, pHeight);

mapImage.SetPixel(x + xx, y + yy, Color.Black);
map.Image = mapImage;

map.Image.Save(@"C:\Users\Skye\Pictures\!Access\Map\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHmmss") + ".png");
```

Comment: You really should dispose of your disposable objects. You can easily get OutOfMemoryExecptions even if you have tons of free memory due to the way GDI+ and .NET interact.